# custom menu widget where menu title is a link

Tags: menus, links

I am looking for, like the title of this question indicates, a custom menu in wordpress where the menu title itself is a link. It seems like a very simple thing, but after a lot of searching I've come up with nothing.

More explanation:

Here is what I have:

```
My Custom Menu
  Link 1 (goes to page 1)
  Link 2 (goes to page 2)
  Link 3 (goes to page 3)
```

Here is what I want:

```
My Custom Menu (goes to w/e page I choose to link it to)
  Link 1 (goes to page 1)
  Link 2 (goes to page 2)
  Link 3 (goes to page 3)
```

Simple, right? So, is there a plugin for this, or do I need to write on?

Comment: Any progress? Was my answer helpful? Do you still miss something?

Comment: @toscho That is an excellent question. I'm afraid it's been so long, now, that I do not recall. If someone wishes to verify your answer as working, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the title of most widgets and change the markup. The name of the filter is `'widget_title'` and the third parameter tells you the type of the filtered widget.

Sample code, not tested:

```
add_filter( 'widget_title', 'wpse_52108_nav_widget_title_link', 30, 3 );

/**
 * Changes the title for the nav menu widget.
 *
 * @param string $title
 * @param string $instance
 * @param string $id_base
 * @return string
 */
function wpse_52108_nav_widget_title_link( $title, $instance = NULL, $id_base = '' )
{
    return 'nav_menu' === $id_base ? "<a href='http://example.com'>$title</a>" : $title;
}
```

The `$id_base` is the first parameter in `parent::__construct()` in the widget class. For the nav menu widget it is:

```
parent::__construct( 'nav_menu', __('Custom Menu'), $widget_ops );
```